# Обработка запросов nginx

Tags: nginx, request, php-fpm

На сервер nginx из стороннего терминала приходят такие запросы

```
192.168.1.132 - - [10/Oct/2019:18:18:47 +0600] "9900802.00AY1AZFCA0" 400 173 "-" "-"
```

Как обработать или настроить nginx чтобы принимать такие запросы?

Настройки nginx у меня такие

```
server {
    listen 6001;
    server_name localhost;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/sip2-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/sip2-error.log;
    root /var/www/sip2/public_html;

    location / {
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }}
```

После добавления уровня логирования info

```
2019/10/10 20:36:03 [info] 5296#0: *1 client sent invalid method while reading client request line, client: 192.168.1.132, server: localhost, request: "9900802.00AY1AZFCA0"
2019/10/10 20:36:05 [info] 5296#0: *2 client sent invalid method while reading client request line, client: 192.168.1.132, server: localhost, request: "9900802.00AY1AZFCA0"
```

Update 11.10.2019

Решил сделать веб-сокет php на определенном порту и запустить его как демона.

Comment: [Комментарий Максима Дунина на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315832/how-to-fix-nginx-throws-400-bad-request-headers-on-any-header-testing-tools#comment16555393_12315832): когда nginx возвращает 400 (Bad Request), он регистрирует причину в журнале ошибок на уровне «info». Следовательно, очевидный способ выяснить, что происходит, - это настроить [error_log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log) для регистрации сообщений на уровне «info» и просматривать журнал ошибок при тестировании.

Comment: Если хотите посмотреть что именно приходит (весь запрос), поставьте MITM-прокси, например [этот](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/) позволяет и в консоли смотреть, и веб-интерфейс поднимает.